# Storing images in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Please give me the query for inserting images in a MySQL database. I am new to stackoverflow, so please ignore me if my question is not up to mark.

Comment: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6472268/7678788) as the best solution...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you can't store a reference to the image, rather than the actual image?

Images are big—they make databases big. SQL can be painful (as it's not object-oriented) and doesn't have an image type.

You could store them as a `BLOB`... if you want to write all the coding, encoding, checking, etc.

Comment: Particular reason? uhmm, let us think. 1- It's not a web appllication and no web server is installed on the machine (to serve the images to the clients)? 2- Plus no file sharing preferred? 3- An application that has a feature to connect remote database & configuration? I can count lots more...

Answer (score 19):

If the image is located on your MySQL host, you could use the [`LOAD_FILE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) function to store the image in a `BLOB` field:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (id INT, image BLOB);

INSERT INTO MyTable (id, image) VALUES(1, LOAD_FILE('/tmp/your_image.png'));
```

You have to make sure that the image file is readable by MySQL, and that the MySQL user has the `FILE` privilege. To grant the `FILE` privilege, log-in as root and execute:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'mysql_user'@'localhost';
```

Comment: i have given path in load_file as(c:\dir\a.jpg) but after performing `select` operation I see NULL(not my img) being stored, why?

Comment: @gautam: It looks like a permissions problem. You have to make sure that the file you are reading can be read by the MySQL service.

Comment: @gautam: In addition, I think in Windows you need to specify your path like this: `'c:\\dir\\a.jpg'`

Comment: It's not working and be null, too...

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `BLOB` field to do this, but I would generally not recommend that.  It's almost always better to simply store the image on the filesystem and store the path to the image in the database.

ETA:

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) for more discussion

Answer (score 0):

It is always a better idea to store images in external folders and store the refrence in the database.

Here is the step by step guide to upload images in the database.
http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql/7

http://forum.codecall.net/topic/40286-tutorial-storing-images-in-mysql-with-php/

Here is the link for step by step guide for retreival of images from the database
http://forum.codecall.net/topic/40849-tutorial-storing-images-in-mysql-with-php-part-ii-display-your-images/

Some more information on BLOB
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,17671,27914