# How to store images in Mysql table ?

Tags: mysql, image

How would someone store a image in MySql ? Would I have to store it as a Blob ?

That's if its even possible can't see why it wouldn't be though.

Comment: It is possible but **why** do you need that?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527801/php-to-store-images-in-mysql-or-not?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing images in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014578/storing-images-in-mysql)

Comment: Please search for existing questions before you add a new one - this topic has been covered on numerous occasions. As recommendation, you should also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay as to why you most likely don't want to do this.

Comment: [storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/)

Comment: What have you done uptill now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always store the file path for where the image is located, instead of actually storing the image itself.

Comment: That wasn't the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BLOB to store images in database. But I think recommended way is to store the image path in the database not the whole image

Answer (score -1):

You can store images in database if you require security.
But if you store image as blob it slow down your application. Retrieving images from folder is much faster. and another problem is If database is corrupted, no way to retrieve.

Comment: Give reference to "much faster".